# Pass constructor parameter into factory in Google Guice

Tags: java, guice

I am trying to pass a constructor parameter from one class into the factory for another class:

```
public class PerPixelImageUpdater implements ImageUpdater {
    private final PixelUpdater pixelUpdater;
    private final BufferedImage image;

    @Inject
    PerPixelImageUpdater(PixelUpdaterFactory pixelUpdaterFactory,
                         @Assisted BufferedImage image){
        this.image = image;
        this.pixelUpdater = pixelUpdaterFactory.create(image);
    }

    //Methods
}
```

Factory:

```
public interface ImageUpdaterFactory {
    ImageUpdater create(BufferedImage image);
}
```

Register in Guice:

```
install(new FactoryModuleBuilder()
                .implement(ImageUpdater.class, PerPixelImageUpdater.class)
                .build(ImageUpdaterFactory.class));
```

When I run this code I get an error that the implementation was not bound?

> 1) No implementation for java.awt.image.BufferedImage annotated with
>   @com.google.inject.assistedinject.Assisted(value="") was bound.
>   while locating java.awt.image.BufferedImage annotated with
>   @com.google.inject.assistedinject.Assisted(value="")
>       for the 2nd parameter of com.infojolt.imageencrypt.PerPixelImageUpdater.(PerPixelImageUpdater.java:16)

What have I missed? Do I need to register the factory in a different way?

---

Extra details:

There are actually two errors

> 1) No implementation for java.awt.image.BufferedImage annotated with
>   @com.google.inject.assistedinject.Assisted(value="") was bound.
>   while locating java.awt.image.BufferedImage annotated with
>   @com.google.inject.assistedinject.Assisted(value="")
>       for the 2nd parameter of com.infojolt.imageencrypt.PerPixelImageUpdater.(PerPixelImageUpdater.java:16)
>   at
>   com.infojolt.imageencrypt.Injection.ImageEncryptModule.configure(ImageEncryptModule.java:25)
>
> 2) No implementation for java.awt.image.BufferedImage annotated with
>   @com.google.inject.assistedinject.Assisted(value="") was bound.
>   while locating java.awt.image.BufferedImage annotated with
>   @com.google.inject.assistedinject.Assisted(value="")
>       for the 3rd parameter of com.infojolt.imageencrypt.SimplePixelUpdater.(SimplePixelUpdater.java:17)
>   at
>   com.infojolt.imageencrypt.Injection.ImageEncryptModule.configure(ImageEncryptModule.java:18)

In `PixelShiftImageEncrypter`, `ImageUpdaterFactory imageUpdaterFactory` is passed in to the constructor:

```
@Inject
PixelShiftImageEncrypter(PixelShiftCalculator pixelShiftCalculator,
                                ImageLoader imageLoader,
                                StringEncryption stringEncryption,
                                PixelModificationCalculator pixelModificationCalculator,
                                PixelSkipCountCalculator pixelSkipCountCalculator,
                                ImageUpdaterFactory imageUpdaterFactory)
```

*(I am currently refactoring this project to reduce the number of constructor args / method params, but I'm trying to get the classed under test before ripping it apart.)*

`ImageUpdater` is then created in a method by calling:

```
ImageUpdater imageUpdater = imageUpdaterFactory.create(image);
```

`PixelShiftImageEncrypter` is created in:

```
@Inject
EncryptJobConfiguration(@Assisted("inputString") String inputString,
                        @Assisted("secretKey") String secretKey,
                        @Assisted("inputImagePath") String inputImagePath,
                        ImageEncrypter imageEncrypter,
                        ImageStorage imageStorage)
```

`ImageEncryptModule.java` contains:

```
install(new FactoryModuleBuilder()
            .implement(JobConfiguration.class, Names.named("encrypt"), EncryptJobConfiguration.class)
            .implement(JobConfiguration.class, Names.named("decrypt"), DecryptJobConfiguration.class)
            .build(JobConfigurationFactory.class));

    install(new FactoryModuleBuilder()
            .implement(PixelUpdater.class, SimplePixelUpdater.class)
            .build(PixelUpdaterFactory.class));

    install(new FactoryModuleBuilder()
            .implement(ImageUpdater.class, PerPixelImageUpdater.class)
            .build(ImageUpdaterFactory.class));
```

`PixelUpdaterFactory`:

```
public interface PixelUpdaterFactory {
    PixelUpdater create(BufferedImage image);
}
```

`JobConfigurationFactory`:

```
public interface JobConfigurationFactory {
    @Named("encrypt")
    JobConfiguration createEncrypt(@Assisted("inputString") String inputString,
                                   @Assisted("secretKey") String secretKey,
                                   @Assisted("inputImagePath") String inputImagePath);

    @Named("decrypt")
    JobConfiguration createDecrypt(@Assisted("secretKey") String secretKey,
                                   @Assisted("inputImagePath") String inputImagePath);
}
```

This file also contains all of the other bindings which I've exclude for brevity. For example:

```
bind(ImageEncrypter.class).to(PixelShiftImageEncrypter.class);
```

Comment: Can you also add the line that is throwing this exception? How are you accessing the create method of the `ImageUpdaterFactory` factory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that I thought I had replaced:

```
bind(ImageUpdater.class).to(PerPixelImageUpdater.class);
```

with:

```
install(new FactoryModuleBuilder()
                .implement(ImageUpdater.class, PerPixelImageUpdater.class)
                .build(ImageUpdaterFactory.class));
```

However, the original binding hadn't been removed. Deleting these two line solved the problem:

```
bind(ImageUpdater.class).to(PerPixelImageUpdater.class);
bind(PixelUpdater.class).to(SimplePixelUpdater.class);
```